# Durch-reisen vs durchreisen

Tags: preposition, separable-verb, verb-choice

Wie oben erwähnt, wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen 'durch-reisen/ ist durchgereist' und 'durchreisen/ hat durchreist'?

Z. B.

Wir reisen durch Rom durch (findet ihr Muttersprachler*Innen übrigens diese Wiederholung irgendwie unnuzt?)

Wir durchreisen Rom

Comment: "Wir reisen durch Rom durch." You are travelling and happen to go through Rom. "Wir durchreisen Rom." You are travelling in Rom. Have you seen the [Duden entries](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/durchreisen)?

Comment: Welcome Tristan. *Wir reisen durch Rom durch.* ist umgangssprachlich in Ordnung imo. Du solltest aber deine eigenen Einschätzungen, Recherchen und Begründungen für eventuelle Verwirrung mitteilen, um nicht Gefahr zu laufen, dass deine Frage geschlossen wird, weil ja hier das Rad nicht neu erfunden wird und wir hier kein neues Wörterbuch anlegen wollen. ;)

Comment: Thank you both! Yes, I always check the Duden dictionary, but it sometimes happens to be not totally clear to me 

Comment: This kind of "double" preposition occurs a lot in German, being a consequence the way separable verbs are usually formed. The most common example is *Pass auf dich auf!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. durchreisen / hat durchreist

> Goethe hat Italien im Laufe seines Lebens mehrfach durchreist.

Bedeutung: Innerhalb eines Gebietes reisen, z.B. von Stadt zu Stadt in Italien.

2. durchreisen / ist durchgereist

> Auf unserem Weg nach Italien sind wir durch die Schweiz durchgereist.
> Auf unserem Weg nach Neapel sind wir in der Schweiz durchgereist.
> Auf unserem Weg nach Italien sind wir durch die Schweiz gereist.
> Wir sind gerade auf dem Weg nach Italien und reisen hier nur durch.

Bedeutung: Durch ein Gebiet in ein anderes reisen. Das doppelte "durch" kann man benutzen, ist aber natürlich nicht schön. Es geht auch "in", oder man läßt das "durch" im Verb dann eben einfach weg. In dem letzten Beispiel wird klarer, warum es das zusammengesetzte Verb überhaupt gibt.

Comment: Super! Vielen Dank

Comment: Mir ist eine andere Frage in den Sinn gekommen. Sie haben mich drauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass manchmal die trennbare Präposition weggelassen werden kann. Gilt das aber auch für anscheinend ähnliche Fälle, wie z. B. 'Ich sehe durch die Scheibe durch' vs 'Ich sehe durch die Scheibe'?

Comment: "Sie haben mich drauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass manchmal die trennbare Präposition weggelassen werden kann." Nein, das ändert das Verb von "durchreisen" zu "reisen". Dasselbe mit "durchsehen"/"sehen".

Comment: Genau, das Verb ändert sich, und man muss im Einzelfall sehen, ob das noch denselben Sinn hat. Bei "durchreisen" und "durchsehen" hängt es davon ab, was man betonen möchte. Zum Beispiel bei "Kann man durch die Gardine durchsehen?" (Ist die Gardine transparent?) würde ich es nicht verkürzen.

Comment: *"Das doppelte "durch" kann man benutzen, ist aber natürlich nicht schön"*: Manchmal trägt es jedoch zur Klarstellung und Bedeutungsunterscheidung bei: *Auf dem Weg von Panama in die USA sind wir durch Mittelamerika gereist* (touristischer Aufenthalt in Mittelamerika) vs. *Auf dem Weg von Panama in die USA sind wir durch Mittelamerika durchgereist* (auf mehr oder weniger dem direkten Weg).